# Rewrite URL: domain.com/project to project.com

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

In `.htaccess`, what is the correct way to convert all URLs like this:

`http://domain.com/original-project-name/`

...into this?

`http://new-project-domain.com/`

Closest I found was [this](http://michaelkrol.com/2007/09/12/change-your-domain-name-and-keep-your-incoming-links-with-htaccess/) but it's not quite what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^original-project-name/(.*)$ http://new-project-domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If you don't want any of the rest of the URI to be included in the redirect, remove the `$1` from the rule's target.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been clearer. Editing my question slightly.